# Why does a browser respond much faster to an API requests compared to using a programming language?

Tags: api, browser, response, timing

When calling GET `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` in a browser (Chrome v107) I get response timings around `30ms`

Also when I run following snippet in Chrome Dev Tools Console, same timings

```js
const start = Date.now();
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(() => console.log((Date.now() - start) + 'ms'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

But when I run following snippet in NodeJS v18 (with e.g. `axios`), I get around `140ms` up to `200ms`

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const start = Date.now();
axios
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(() => console.log((Date.now() - start) + 'ms'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I even wrote following script in Rust and got around `130ms` up to `160ms`

```rs
fn main() {
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed is: {:?}", duration);
}
```

---

I tested this on Arch Linux x86_64 5.15.76-1-lts and on a MacOS 13.0, same results

---

I would like to know and learn why this is like that and if I can do any kind of optimization to get faster response timings in NodeJS

Comment: Use Wireshark to compare the traffic. What's the difference? We cannot tell.

Comment: If you're doing this multiple times in a row, it seems likely the still-running browser can reuse (parts of) previous connections. Look at TCP fast open, TLS session resumption, HTTP3, …

Comment: Is it possible that this is just because you've run it on your browser before? When I tried this the first time I run the JavaScript in Chrome it takes around 245ms, and in rust, it is around 70-80ms